# Codeigniter htaccess to remove index.php and www

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to get my htaccess rewrite rules to remove the `index.php` from the url AND also redirect the `www.` requests to the non-www version.

This is my htaccess which works fine with removing the index.php:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

And I came across another question on how to remove the `www` part:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But I just cant seem to get them to play nicely together!  Any advice/suggestions most appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

`RewriteEngine On` "starts" rewriting. `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` work as pairs. 
Here, we send user to non-www version first, and cleans URLs.

Comment: I have exactly the same question, but, it didn´t worked for me.
I also tried removing index_page of the config but it neither worked.
Some suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

You first need to make sure that the "non-www" rewrite rule comes first and then the one that will redirect all requests to the CodeIgniter bootstrap file. Do note that the following code will honor only HTTP rewrites. If you also need HTTPS it requires some modifications.

```
RewriteEngine on
# Sending all www requests to the non-www version.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# Now the CodeIgniter part
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```