# htaccess force www and remove index.php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

Currently I have htaccess which removes index.php from URL, its working fine. But now I want to force url to start with `www`.

My current code:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

I tried following code, but its not working:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/index.php?/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But its not working, I am using codeigniter

Comment: possible duplicate of [Codeigniter htaccess to remove index.php and www](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030990/codeigniter-htaccess-to-remove-index-php-and-www)

Comment: This question is not same, here I am asking not to remove www, instead force for www. Please read properly

Comment: No... Not an EXACT duplicate, but the answer IS still there. `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change order of your rule and keep redirects before rewrite rules:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```