# Removed WWW from URL in codeigniter, controller doesn't access

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to run my CodeIgniter app on localhost when I run the app the URL seem likes `https://www.localhost/projects/4all/` 

then I made changes to `.htaccess` the www is removed but my controller doesn't access now .e.g

When I enter `localhost/projects/4all/` it shows me a blank page.

It doesn't redirect to controller define in `routes.php`

`.htaccess` before I made changes

```
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
  mod_gzip_on Yes
  mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
  mod_gzip_item_include file \.(html?|txt|css|js)$
  mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
  mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
  mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www)\.(.*)\.(.*)\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%2.%3.%4/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]

#force www on production domain

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]



DirectoryIndex index.php
Options -Indexes

RewriteRule ^combine/(.*)$ /application/cache/smarty/cached/$1 [L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|sitemap\.rss)

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

`.htaccess` after I made changes:

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Comment me if some extra data needed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Codeigniter htaccess to remove index.php and www](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030990/codeigniter-htaccess-to-remove-index-php-and-www)

Comment: no mine is deffrent i have already removed index.php and www,
my problem is not showing default controller after removing of www and index.php

Comment: It might be your new `.htaccess` causes `apache` errors. Look at the apache error log to see if this is the cause.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot run the Base URL like https://www.localhost/projects/4all/ on the localhost.
It should be specified as http://localhost/projects/4all/