# Remove www from domain in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

This is what I have in my .htaccess file and when I ran a speed test the www is showing and also shows in all URLs, please help if you know what is broken.

```html
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=off
RewriteRule .* http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|images|robots\.txt|css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: your problem seems unclear...

Comment: Possible duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030990/codeigniter-htaccess-to-remove-index-php-and-www

Comment: I do not see a www in the .htaccess file so why is the WWW showing up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally The base url is same as that of your domain name. It contains www as well.
You can call your css,js and image files using the base url.
www is not a matter to call those files.

Comment: Yes, I edited the config.php file and added the proper base URL. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Use below rule:-

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI}[R=301,L]
```

OR

write your domain name in rule

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

In Codeigniter,  You can set base url as below

```
$root=(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https://" : "http://").$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$root.= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), '', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$config['base_url'] = $root;
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: I do not want to setup a redirect, I just want no www infront of my domain. Is this possible without a redirect? Do all CodeIgniter apps have www by default?

Comment: Yes. You need to replace www to http. There is no wrong way by doing it.

Comment: Sorry, someone else posted that first. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: No need to say sorry. The only thing matters your problem is resolved :)